# how to know which perl interpreter is being used to execute current perl program

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a script called `foo` and looks like below:

```
#!/bin/perl
eval 'exec perl5 -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;
```

Based upon my understanding, if I run `perl foo` or `foo`, the system perl will be used to execute my script (i.e. `/usr/bin/perl` which is specified in shebang line). However, if I run my script `./foo` then the perl interpret being used is `perl5` inside `eval` statement.

I want to verify my theory and I need to find a way to find out which perl interpreter is invoked to execute my script.

Is there anyway to do so?

Thanks much!

**EDIT1:** I think I nail this code chunk and I write a [blog post](https://zeyuanhu.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/understanding-shebang-eval-combo-from-ancient-perl-script/) on it. Please check it out if you still have confusion on the above code chunk.

Comment: No, the shebang runs `/bin/perl` specifically and explicitly, and the `exec` would only run when the script was run by a shell (so `sh script.pl` or similar). This `exec` hack is a holdover from some ancient primitive systems which did not support the shebang specification.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the answer below , I can experiment out and you are correct. Thanks!

Comment: `$]` will get you the version, but `$^X` will name the interpreter

Comment: @ikegami Will ``$^X`` gives the same result as ``use Config;
my $perl = $Config{perlpath};``? From what I saw, the result is slightly different. Thanks much for the help!

Comment: @Jerry, No relation between the two. (e.g. `ln $( which perl ) foo ; foo -E'say $^X'`)

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can find the version of perl interpreter currently script executing in, using perl special veriable. `$^V`

Comment: Uh, that's the version, not the path (which is in `$^X`).